# Unable to execute /usr/local/bin/scrapyd-deploy: No such file or directory

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to get scrapyd to deploy but everytime I run the command

```
sudo scrapyd-deploy local
```

I get the following error

```
Unable to execute /usr/local/bin/scrapyd-deploy: No such file or directory
```

I did the following to try and trouble shoot

```
reinstall python
pip install scrapy
pip install scrapyd
pip install scrapyd-client
```

I checked usr/local/bin and found that the following files exist

```
scrapy
scrapyd
scrapyd-deploy
```

I'm not sure why the scrapy files exist in the folder but when I try to run scrapyd-deploy local it cannot find them.

Comment: Provide your "setup.py" file content, please.

Comment: Also, have you restarted your machine? and/or the terminal?

Comment: It is very likely that `scrapyd-deploy` is a broken symlink; `/bin/ls -l /usr/local/bin/` may help show what's going on, as would `head -1 /usr/local/bin/scrapyd-deploy`

Answer (score 0):

I had upgraded to os mojave after which all of the errors started. When I first tired to run scrapyd, brew installed python.

I was able to resolve issue by starting over.

I did the following:
brew uninstall python
pip uninstall scrapy
pip uninstall scrapyd
pip uninstall scrapyd-client
I deleted docker

I then reinstalled scrapyd-client after which the error resolved and I was able to deploy scrapyd.